# Magento 2 - New storeview redirects back to default store view - status code 302

Tags: magento2, redirect, store-view, htaccess, stores

I created a new storeview accessible under the URL app.example.com

I added this to the **.htaccess** to set the **MAGE_RUN_CODE** Environment Variable to app if the URL app.example.com is called:

```
SetEnv MAGE_RUN_TYPE store
SetEnvIf Host ^example.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=default
SetEnvIf Host ^www.example.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=default

SetEnvIf Host ^app.example.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=app
SetEnvIf Host ^www.app.example.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=app
```

Then I changed the **base url** of my new store view to http://app.example.com/

**Problem:**

I created a new CMS page **for the new storeview** with the URL Key `app-test`.
But if I try to access it via app.example.com/app-test, then I get redirected to https://www.example.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=app+test

I tried to **reindex** and **flush cache**, but it made no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The problem is, that my domain points to the **pub** folder, but I added my code to the **.htaccess** in the root directory of magento.

After I moved my code to `pub/.htaccess`, it works.

---

If this does not work, then try to delete your **cookies** too.

Comment: keep the code inside <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>